# Xcode error in Upload symbol files file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-crash-reporting

I have followed proper steps for firebase crash reporting integration but I still have errors like this,

> /Users/satish/Desktop/firebase_crash/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym:174:
>   error: Please ensure you've followed the steps at:: command not found
>
> /Users/satish/Desktop/firebase_crash/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym:175:
>   error: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files:
>   No such file or directory
>
> /Users/satish/Desktop/firebase_crash/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym:197:
>   error: All attempts to find the service account JSON file have failed.

Here is the image of the error that I have faced.
[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Solved in Xcode 8.3.1 with replacing
**upload-sym** with **upload-sym-util.bash** in script

**new script**

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=xxxxxxxxxx

"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash "${PROJECT_DIR}/medinfo-a7f29-firebase-crashreporting-jv418-3f88c3fc5a.json"
```

Comment: Or you can just use fresh copy of MacOS and Xcode 8.3 which will work with old script

Comment: I just check that `upload-sym-util.bash` are just defining some functions. that means after running `upload-sym-util.bash`, you won't upload the symbol file to firebase. So basically, it is just skipping running `upload-sym` command. So, it doesn't really fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another way to fix this issue.

Run the command in terminal

```
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#set_up_crash_reporting

**Happy to help :)**

Answer (score 1):

### **In Xcode 12**:

As Google change Fabric to **FirebaseCrashlytics** this script doesn't work anymore:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash
```

### Instead, we should use this one:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

be aware of the location for file: **GoogleService-Info.plist**

if it is inside a folder you should specify it:

```
"${PROJECT_DIR}/{Folder Name}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

[image: Firebase Crashlytics build phases script]

**flags:**

- -gsp => google service path
- -p => platform

Answer (score 0):

this is my App settings hope this help you to solve this issue

1- the first thing i did is to update the podfile from pod 'Firebase/Crash' to pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

2 update the debug optaion [click here to open the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlDNY.png)

add the code run crashlytics run code [click here to open the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhASM.png)

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}

$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

3 - clean your build

4 - rerun your code