# Firebase Crash symbol file: Unable to upload symbol file (reason unknown)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have compile error on Xcode 9, and error is `Upload: Unable to upload symbol file (reason unknown)`.

Project compiles successfully on some computer, but not on my side and few of my friend side.

I already have tried to clean project and build folder, deleted derived data and restart computer.

All doesn't works for me.

Here is the screenshot of the error

[image: This is screenshot of xcode]

Thanks

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363895/182544 Worked for me

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @E-Madd solution suggestion worked for me.

Comment: @MobileStar Have you solved this problem? I've got the same issue.

Comment: @E-Madd suggestion works but not act like as we want. The script runs without any warning or error, but crashes won t be symbolicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase Crashlytics instead of Firebase Crash Reporting.

Comment: Just a heads-up: when I migrated from Firebase Crash Reporting to Crashlytics, the script at Build Phases -> Run script was NOT removed and kept causing the error for me. So if someone's migrated, check to see if the FirebaseCrash script is still configured. If it is, just removed the line.

Answer (score 21):

You need to make some changes in **TARGETS -> Build Phases -> Run Scipt**

replace upload-sym with upload-sym-util.bash in script

[image]

Like below

[image]

**Happy to help :)**

Comment: For clarity.
This: 
`FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${JSON_FILE}"`
Changes to:
`FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash "${JSON_FILE}"`

Comment: Worked, build is now working again! Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

I have found how to avoid this issue.
Clean project, delete all derived data and close Xcode.
And then, please run below command on terminal.

```
$ rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.Symbol*
```

And open your project on Xcode and build again.
Sometimes got same issue, but try above steps one or two times again.
This will works for you most of time.

Comment: should be $ rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.Symbol*

Comment: @user1139921 solution worked from me

rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.Symbol*

Comment: Worked for me @mobileStar