# Why do I have to clean and restart project in order to run project with Firebase/Crash script file

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Any idea why is that I have to clean my project, delete `com.google.Symbol*` and restart XCode every time I build a project that uses Firebase/Crash?

The problem seem to be with the uploading symbols `script` for Firebase/Crash.

Here is the process I need to perform everytime I want to run the project.

1. Clean project with (Shif+Command+K)
2. In the terminal delete com.google.Symbol
   `rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.Symbol*`
3. Restart XCode
4. Run. It works fine but only one time, if I run it a second time I get an error.

ERROR: This is the error I get if I run the project a second time.

[image]

Here is my project and the path for the script.
[image]

If I check the `Run script only when installing` option in XCode, the project runs fine every time, but errors don't get symbolicated when shown in Firebase console.

Any idea what could I do to solve this issue?

FYI - I tried changing the path as follow but the behavior was the same.

`"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/Firebase-keys/firebase-crashreporting.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue a few days ago, and it was really annoying. Use this script instead of the current one, this worked for me:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash ${SRCROOT}/Project/Firebase_Crash.json
```

Comment: This seems to be working, I haven't check Firebase to see if errors are actually symbolicating. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: @ incmiko - Are your crashes symbolicated in Firebase? Mine aren't. The script in XCode compiles fine but errors are not symbolicated when shown in the Firebase console.

Comment: I faced the same sadly. I recommend to switch back

Comment: So you went back to the original script, is this how yours look now? ... `"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase-keys/firebase-crashreporting.json"` Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'm using that script, but first I m logging in to my gmail account in safari, which connected to the firebase project, and than calling this method rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload* , and than build & run, but actually I'm running the upload script just for archive

Comment: here is another answer for this problem, try that too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518944/firebase-crash-symbol-file-unable-to-upload-symbol-file-reason-unknown?rq=1

Comment: Oh, so you only run it for archiving, right before submitting to the Appstore?  One last thing, are you using `${PROJECT_DIR}` or static path `/Users/UserName/SomeFolder`. I have noticed that for some reason when you use a static path it works a little better.

Comment: I just checked the "Run script only when installing"